# What does the meaning of the definition-In itself-in the context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

(In itself :in its true nature)OLD

Example:-In itself, it's not a difficult problem to solve.

Plz make it clear what does "in itself" mean in the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In itself" is used to refer to something *without any context*, in contrast with *its influence in a certain context*.

Like, imagine you bring a bottle of wine to a dinner party, and it turns out the host is a recovering alcoholic and gets upset. In that situation, your bottle of wine wasn't a bad gift *in itself*, because wine is normally a very good choice to bring to a dinner, but *in that context*, it happened to be a very bad choice.

Comment: 'In its true nature' meaning?

Comment: @Sam Not the same thing. "In its true nature" means how something really is in contrast with how it looks on the surface. There's no reference to context. "A wolf in sheep's clothing" means someone who appears kind, but *in their true nature* is a mean person.

Comment: Lovely answer and comment. + 1

Answer (score 1):

American Macmillan Dictionary gave following definition for "in itself/of itself" phrase:

> used for emphasizing that what you are saying about one particular thing is true without even considering anything else

For examples:

1. *Some of the medicines were out of date, which was **in itself** dangerous.*
2. *Using someone else’s name is not **of itself** a crime, unless there is an intention to commit a fraud.*